# Does the pressure valve on the wall need to replaced

Tags: water-pressure

Hi I just got my hot water tank replaced and the repair man said that the water pressure was to strong and that I need replace the pressure valve. And that the part costs $500. Is this true or am I getting ripped off sincerely new home owner

Comment: Sounds like a ripoff to me a top of the line brass regulator or the ones I have used are well under 100$ for a 1 inch ported model. Many regulators a rebuild kit can fix the problem for 10-20 bucks.

Comment: In agree with  @EdBeal price comment.  In addition you need a second option.  If they just told you it’s “too strong” that’s pretty arbitrary.  Do you have a gauge what does it show?

Answer (score 1):

Having replaced the water heater in my home recently, and also having a surprise needed replacement of the pressure reducing valve too, I can sympathies with your situation.

If you are just replacing the Pressure-Reducing valve for your home, you can find [Pressure-Reducing valves](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Plumbing-Valves-Pressure-Regulators/N-5yc1vZca1z) from $50 to $150 at your local big box home improvement store. For our project we spent around $95 to match the size of the threads to the previous arrangment.

Also when working on hot water heaters and valves, I learned that this is also the time to have a [Expansion tank](https://www.homedepot.com/s/expansion%2520tank?NCNI-5) installed, or replaced. If this is also something in the agenda, you are looking at around $40-90 at the same retail outlet.

Also factor in cost for copper / pex, etc fittings, and any tools that you need and there should be your cost to do it yourself.

Depending on the plumbing in the home, it could take anywhere from minutes to hours (like mine) to replace. I'd recommend having someone confident in the task to complete the job. It's possible to do it on your own, just make sure to do your thorough research.

If possible, request a itemized list of expenses for the project to help you understand the high cost. If unable to be provided with that, I'd recommend shopping around for another plumber as this does seem high.

Comment: I agree ( check out rebuild kits way cheaper).+

Comment: Concerning the need for an expansion tank, could one just depend on the pressure relief valve on the hot water tank to keep the pressure below the point of damage? Or could one plumb in a pressure relief valve somewhere to drip into a drain to relieve pressure?